# How to make async_write_some() data argument in the buffer dynamic with C++ boost::asio?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, boost, tcp

I've been making a simple server using boost::asio. I've used Boost's docs to create basics and ran into a problem:
I want a client to be able to send the server a command, so I want the server to be able to respond to that. I use async_write_some() and async_read_some(), as shown in the docs.
I use m_Data member to store whatever a client sent to the server, but I don't know how to make that async_write_some() send a certain thing.

Connection.hpp

```
using namespace boost::asio;

class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
    private:
        ip::tcp::socket m_Socket;
        std::string     m_Msg;
        uint16_t        m_MaxLen;
        char*           m_Data;

    public:
        Connection(boost::asio::io_service& _ioSrvc);

        static boost::shared_ptr<Connection> Create(boost::asio::io_service& _ioSrvc);
        ip::tcp::socket&                     Socket();

        void Start();

        void HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& _err, size_t _bytes);
        void HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& _err, size_t _bytes);
};
```

Connection.cpp

```
Connection::Connection(boost::asio::io_service& _ioSrvc)
    : m_Socket(_ioSrvc), m_Msg("placeholder_message"), m_MaxLen(1024), m_Data(new char[m_MaxLen]) { }

boost::shared_ptr<Connection> Connection::Create(boost::asio::io_service& _ioSrvc) {
    return boost::shared_ptr<Connection>(new Connection(_ioSrvc));
}

ip::tcp::socket& Connection::Socket() {
    return m_Socket;
}

void Connection::Start() {
    m_Socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_Data, m_MaxLen),
                             boost::bind(&Connection::HandleRead, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    m_Socket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_Msg, m_MaxLen),
                              boost::bind(&Connection::HandleWrite, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}

void Connection::HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& _err, size_t _bytes) {
    if (!_err) {
        std::cout << m_Data << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]: " << _err.message() << std::endl;
        m_Socket.close();
    }
}

void Connection::HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& _err, size_t _bytes) {
    if (!_err) {
        std::cout << "!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]: " << _err.message() << std::endl;
        m_Socket.close();
    }
}
```

I know it takes a buffer, which takes a reference to a string, so I thought that changing the original string, which is m_Msg member, would result in server being able to dynamically change the response to whatever I wanted, but it didn't work, it looked like the buffer took a copy instead of a reference, though I'm sure I saw that std::string& arg in it. I tried to change the m_Msg member in HandleRead() method, using outside method and many stuff but nothing worked for me, the client would always end up receiving "placeholder_message", which m_Msg is set to in the constructor.

So basically, I want to send various data based on the received data and I don't know how to do that and I'm asking for help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why didn't you provide [mcve]? Your current code doesn't match the description in your question. Where is an attempt to reassign `m_Msg` and sending ? If answer of server should depend on client request, you cannot start two asynchronous operations at the same time. First should be `read`, when read operation is completed you can send data by `write`. So write should be implemented in `HandleRead`. `buffer` takes string by reference - `buffer(string&)` but it used internal pointer of data stored by string - which is invalidated when any reassign on string is performed.

Comment: So after `m_Msg = X` you should call `buffer` again - `boost::asio::buffer(m_Msg)`.

Comment: @rafix07 I left the code as it was because of many attempts of trying to make it work, so I didn't want to throw like every code that I've tried that didn't work, though I see where you are coming from.  
And thank you for your help, works now!